# Loading audio files through URLs from remote locations (Opera)?

Tags: javascript, opera, codepen, audiocontext

Maybe someone knows why codepend does not load audio files from URLs? (I do not have pro codepen, so I can't use direct uploading of files to pen).

I have this Audio "loader" implementation in my program:

```
// Audio loader implementation.
window.onload = init;
let context;
let bufferLoader;
let greenBuffer = null;
let redBuffer = null;
let blueBuffer = null;
let yellowBuffer = null;
let dohBuffer = null;
let woohooBuffer = null;
let excellentBuffer = null;
let superDohBuffer = null;
// Buffer loader class taken from https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/
function BufferLoader(context, urlList, callback) {
  this.context = context;
  this.urlList = urlList;
  this.onload = callback;
  this.bufferList = new Array();
  this.loadCount = 0;
}

BufferLoader.prototype.loadBuffer = function(url, index) {
  // Load buffer asynchronously
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.responseType = "arraybuffer";

  let loader = this;

  request.onload = function() {
    // Asynchronously decode the audio file data in request.response
    loader.context.decodeAudioData(
      request.response,
      function(buffer) {
        if (!buffer) {
          alert('error decoding file data: ' + url);
          return;
        }
        loader.bufferList[index] = buffer;
        if (++loader.loadCount == loader.urlList.length)
          loader.onload(loader.bufferList);
      },
      function(error) {
        console.error('decodeAudioData error', error);
      }
    );
  }

  request.onerror = function() {
    alert('BufferLoader: XHR error');
  }

  request.send();
}

BufferLoader.prototype.load = function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.urlList.length; ++i)
  this.loadBuffer(this.urlList[i], i);
}
function init() {
    try {
        // Fix up for prefixing
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext;
        context = new AudioContext();
    }
    catch(e) {
        alert('Web Audio API is not supported in this browser');
    }
    bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
        context,
        [
          'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3',
          'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3',
          'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3',
          'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3',
          'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.springfieldfiles.com/sounds/homer/doh.mp3',
          'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.springfieldfiles.com/sounds/homer/woohoo.mp3',
          'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://springfieldfiles.com/sounds/burns/excellnt.mp3',
          'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.springfieldfiles.com/sounds/homer/doheth.mp3',
        ],
        setBuffers
        );

      bufferLoader.load();
}

function setBuffers(bufferList){
    greenBuffer = bufferList[0];
    redBuffer = bufferList[1];
    blueBuffer = bufferList[2];
    yellowBuffer = bufferList[3];
    dohBuffer = bufferList[4];
    woohooBuffer = bufferList[5];
    excellentBuffer = bufferList[6];
    superDohBuffer = bufferList[7];
}
```

If I use this code locally (not on codepen), it works fine. It loads those files and later I can play those audio files how I want. But if I run it on codepen, it throws this (note I also prepended `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` to URLs to bypass CORS):

```
console_runner-079c09a….js:1 decodeAudioData error DOMException: Unable to decode audio data
(anonymous) @ console_runner-079c09a….js:1
(anonymous) @ pen.js:80
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data
```

Full pen can be checked here: https://codepen.io/andriusl/pen/proxKj

**Update.**
It seems this is related with browsers. AudioContext does not properly work with Opera browser, so this question is more oriented to browser than codepen itself.

Comment: Your codepen is working fine for me on a Windows machine! All sounds are playing! What browser are you testing with?

Comment: @JoelCDoyle now that you mentioned it. It seems this is Opera browser problem.. Yesterday I tested it on Ubuntu with Chrome browser and it was working fine, but today I tested on Windows and Opera (somehow thought I was testing with Chrome) and suddenly it stopped working. But I got confused and thought I did not test it on codepen (just locally).

Comment: Makes sense. It looks like Opera support for AudioContext is only "experimental": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext#Browser_compatibility
Here is an issue on github that is very similar:
https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/issues/481#issuecomment-201912133